Concatenating two const arrays at compile time
I want to generate one const array of elements of type struct config; and enumeration enum pin;, which shall be used to index said array, from (configuration) definitions contained in two separate files file1.c/h and file2.c/h that are user modifiable. Its best if I show on specific example what I mean.
I will show you 3 options of how I though about implementing this. Their downsides, and then ask you to help me come up with option 4 that addresses these downsides.
Please note that the examples may be incomplete, they are meant to be used only for presentation purposes.
Option1:
///////////////////////////
// file1.h

#define LIST1 \
    ePin1,    \
    ePin2,    \
    ePin3,

///////////////////////////
// file1.c

#include "file1.h"

enum pin1
{
    LIST1
};

const struct config array1[] =
{
    [ePin1] = {aaa},
    [ePin2] = {bbb},
    [ePin3] = {ccc},
};

///////////////////////////
// file2.h

#define LIST2 \
    ePin4,    \
    ePin5,

///////////////////////////
// file2.c

#include "file2.h"

enum pin2
{
    LIST2
};

const struct config array2[] =
{
    [ePin4] = {ddd},
    [ePin5] = {eee},
};

///////////////////////////
// main.h

#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

enum pin
{
    LIST1
    LIST2
};

///////////////////////////
// main.c

#include "main.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE(array)       (sizeof(array) / sizeof((array)[0]))
#define LIST_SIZE(type, list)   ARRAY_SIZE(((const type[]){list})) 

#define LIST1_SIZE LIST_SIZE(enum pin, LIST1)
#define LIST2_SIZE LIST_SIZE(enum pin, LIST2)

extern const struct config array1[];
extern const struct config array2[];

const struct config * get_config(enum pin)
{
    if (pin >= 0 && pin < LIST1_SIZE)
    {
        return &array1[pin];
    }
    else
    {
        return &array2[pin - LIST1_SIZE];
    }
}

Downsides:

have to create these local enumerations in file1 and file2 to generate 0 based indexes for arrays
if I want to retrieve config I have to determine which array to index based on enumeral value

Option2:
///////////////////////////
// file1.h

#define LIST1 \
    ePin1,    \
    ePin2,    \
    ePin3,

///////////////////////////
// file1.c

#include "file1.h"

enum pin1
{
    LIST1
};

__attribute__((used)) static const struct config array1[] =
{
    [ePin1] = {aaa},
    [ePin2] = {bbb},
    [ePin3] = {ccc},
};

///////////////////////////
// file2.h

#define LIST2 \
    ePin4,    \
    ePin5,

///////////////////////////
// file2.c

#include "file2.h"

enum pin2
{
    LIST2
};

__attribute__((used)) static const struct config array2[] =
{
    [ePin4] = {ddd},
    [ePin5] = {eee},
};

///////////////////////////
// linker_script.lsl
// In linker script we make sure that array2[] is placed immediately after array1[]
// We can also expose address of array[] to .c code, lets name it array_all

///////////////////////////
// main.h

#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

enum pin
{
    LIST1
    LIST2
};

///////////////////////////
// main.c

#include "main.h"

extern const struct config array_all[]; // exposed from linker script

const struct config * get_config(enum pin)
{
    return &array_all[pin];
}

Downsides:

have to create these local enumerations in file1 and file2 to generate 0 based indexes for arrays
not completely portable

Benefits:

returning config is as easy as indexing one array

Option3:
///////////////////////////
// file1.h

#define LIST1     \
    X(ePin1, aaa) \
    X(ePin2, bbb) \
    X(ePin3, ccc)


///////////////////////////
// file2.h

#define LIST2     \
    X(ePin4, ddd) \
    X(ePin5, eee)

///////////////////////////
// main.h

#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

enum pin
{
#define X(pin, ...) pin,
    LIST1
    LIST2
#undef X
};

///////////////////////////
// main.c

#include "main.h"

static const struct config array_all[] =
{
#define X(pin, ...) [pin] = {__VA_ARGS__},
    LIST1
    LIST2
#undef X
};

const struct config * get_config(enum pin)
{
    return &array_all[pin];
}

Downsides:

X macros may not comply well with MISRA-C (though I heard they are compliant with MISRA-C:2012)
X macros may be difficult to understand and debug for newcomers

Benefits:

user only required to define list (not required to define array)
created array is always perfect, that is because it is not under user control where the user could have inserted any random elements not part of enumeration
returning config is as easy as indexing one array
array is static and local only to main.c

Option4:
The best solution so far is using X macros. However we are trying to limit the use of function-like macros to make the code most understandable. How can we accomplish: "One enumeration that indexes config array directly (without any index arithmetic)" in the easiest way possible. I am open to linker modifications as long as they are not extreme and fairly portable.

The question seems well considered, and it is on topic.  However, it is both too open-ended for SO and too subjective.  We expect questions that afford concise, objective answers.

A common solution for problems like this is to generate the code automatically with a script.

@Barmar Not desirable. We want to have configuration information contained in source code.

@user1806687: Input files to scripts are source code. There is nothing significantly different between processing files with scripts and processing files with compilers. They are processing steps that take inputs, produce ouputs, and feed into other steps of the build process. If a compiler is not the best tool for some particular precompilation task, you should avoid abusing its capabilities to do the task.

@EricPostpischil That may be but we do no want another dependency in the build process. It is complicated as it is already.

Of the three alternatives presented, option 3 seems preferable.  Option 1 is unwieldy and scales poorly as you add configuration sources.  Option 2 depends on linker magic that is likely to be even more confusing to the uninitiated than X macros.  With X macros, at least the person (or tool) looking at your source code can find the relevant declarations.  And if necessary, a confused person can obtain enlightenment by running the code through the preprocessor and then a pretty printer.  And if you document it well, then they shouldn't need to do even that.
